# Access MultilingualResources from .cs part of code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have a simple video recorder app that I made multi lingual with the Multilingual app toolkit.  Got an error in it when there is no camera attached, it crashes.  Great coder that I am, didn't even think to trap that out :-)

In any event, now that the code is multilingual, I want the MessageBox letting them know what the problems is to be multilingual also.

Looked all over for this, came up dry.  If worst comes to worst, I could just put an invisible control on the XAML and read it, but would prefer to do something more elegant.  If I could get access to resources from within .cs, it would be ideal. Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks, John.

Comment: Are you developing a uwp app?

Comment: yes, UWP app for the app store.  I was able to do the XAML part easily.  But I just don't know how to access those strings from the .cs code.

Comment: Think I just found it, got to try it out, but is this it?   var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var str = loader.GetString("Farewell");

Comment: I think so, more details please reference [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources)

Comment: Thanks Sunteen. Yeah, that was it, will answer my own question.

Comment: The article you quoted is the one I got it from.  Had a heck of a time finding that though.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this for myself,,,

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader(); 
var str = loader.GetString("Farewell");
```

What I found with researching this, is that most of the docs that come up from searches relate to win 8, not win 10.  In any event, tried and tested, and it does the trick.